# C++ and Windows , CRT

Tags: c++

I am developing application application using C++ VS 2008.
Now I need to either install respective MSM or install redist on customer machine to get this working.

Is there any way in which I can just copy those CRT dlls and get the application running.

Private assembly option seems to be complicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just depend on the CRT, then yes you can simply XCOPY deploy it as a private assembly and it will work just fine.  Put it in the same folder as your application.

Doing this will prevent your application from taking advantage of servicing releases of the CRT though.  This may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Microsoft article:

[How to: Deploy using XCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291.aspx)

Comment: Can you please explain what will following step do :

Run vcredist_x86.exe on the target computer.This installs all Visual C++ libraries as shared assemblies. On a target computer with support for manifest-based binding of applications to their dependencies (Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista) the libraries are installed in the WinSxS folder. On a computer without such support (Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 2000), the libraries are installed to both the WinSxS and System32 folders.

Comment: @Avinash - Look at the second section " Deploying Visual C++ library DLLs as private assemblies." It sounds like this is what you are wanting to do.